# Is there any way to mirror displays in 16:9

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have an old dual core Toshiba laptop with a 15" wide screen that rarely leaves my office.  I have a 17" wide screen monitor plugged into the vga port on the side and want to mirror the display.  when I select the mirror display checkbox the only resolution options I get are in the 4:3 ratio.  Currently I have set the external monitor as display one and disabled the laptop screen, wich is fine for the office, however being a laptop I do occasionally take it on the road and don't want to have to change display setting or bring the external monitor.  Is there some way maybe in the terminal that I can mirror the displays at 16:9 ratio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `arandr` to change screen definitions. It's in the Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Arandr uses draggable rectangles that represent the physical displays - like display-management-software usually does.

Unlike most other software, the displays may overlap, as seen in the screenshot [in this thread](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=112056).

You may also try to fiddle around with the `xrandr` command line tool. The lower-level-approach may allow for more flexibility.

Comment: This seems to work better than the stock GUI for unity.  I couldn't "mirror" and because my laptop has a slightly different aspect ratio I could not set them to the same resolution, but at least if I travel without my monitor my laptop screen will be usable.  I wish there was a way to stretch or shrink on of the displays so part of my desktop wasn't cut off.  I will definitely use this package if I build a multi-screen pc especially if i put more than 2 monitors.  Thanks for the advise:)

Comment: How do we mirror the display?