# Ubuntu MATE: window list on each monitor

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

How can I display window list (open applications) on each monitor?
How can it be set up?

I do not want to mirror displays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to mirror displays in 16:9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727165/is-there-any-way-to-mirror-displays-in-169)